# How can this behaviour of an array of struct pointers be explained?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having an array of struct pointers and assign real students to the array. Here's the code:

```
struct student {
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

typedef struct student* s_ptr;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    s_ptr array = malloc(sizeof(s_ptr) * 4);

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        struct student newStudent = { "john", "smith", x, x, x };
        array[x] = newStudent;
    }

    printf("%d ", array[0].day);
    printf("%d ", array[1].day);
    printf("%d ", array[2].day);
    printf("%d ", array[3].day);

    return 0;

}
```

It compiles but it gives the output

0
2608
2
3

instead of

0
1
2
3

What's happening here? How to fix this?

Comment: The reason is karma. You are getting punished by the universe for hiding a pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: I wouldn't say you shouldn't never do it. You can do your programming in whatever style you like, just be mindful and responsible for the choices. Hiding a pointer in a typedef is perfectly fine. Usually when that's used to encapsulate a data structure then one could also provide functions to initialize such structure properly so the end user of it doesn't have to mess with the internals. Also, functions to deallocate the data are equally handy.

Comment: There is another thing going on here. You say you are having an array of struct pointers. You are not. And again, if you didn't hide your pointer type behind a typedef, it would be much easier to see.

Comment: Try this: `s_ptr array = malloc(sizeof(struct student) * 4);`
You'll be allocation enugh space for `4 students`, not  `4 pointers` !!

Comment: @sidyll Regarding encapsulating a data structure: no, I would still not hide a pointer behind a typedef, because then the programmer thinks that they need to pass on a `HANDLE*` to functions, while `HANDLE` is actually enough. This adds needless obfuscation and makes debugging more difficult. I don't even hide function pointer typedefs behind pointers, but typedef a function type instead.

Comment: @Lundin I appreciate the response and clarification. It might be a bit of personal taste but of course the project context and nature are key in deciding what to use. I'm comfortable with opaque pointers, and should note that frameworks such as Apple's CoreFoundation do use it as a standard. However I can perfectly understand and agree with your argument. I just don't think it generates such bad karma :)

Comment: @sidyll If using opaque pointers and you only allow the caller to declare `type* variable;` rather than `type variable;`, then there's nothing mysterious or magical with `type` - the caller simply doesn't need to care of its internals. One example of this style is the C standard opaque `FILE*`, which is always declared as a pointer. The C standard being a canonical reference of the C language, unlike Apple.

Comment: @Lundin Sure. Well, l think I shall now leave and start the karma cleansing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sizeof(s_ptr)` is the size of a pointer; not the size of a structure.

This is another example of why typedefing pointers (that you mean to use as pointers) is error prone.

Beyond that, you can circumvent such errors by applying `sizeof` to an expression:

```
array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * 4);
```

Now, whatever `array` points at, you will allocate the correct size.